# iOS Simulator always crashes before displaying home page

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I'm new to Mac and iOS.  I got a 2014 Mac Mini to act as a build server for my .NET Maui app development.  In order to publish on the Apple Store I need the latest XCode, so I used OpenCore Legacy Patcher to upgrade to Ventura.  The Mac Mini has 8GB of memory and the GPU supports Metal 2.  Not a great setup I know, but I'm not quite ready to blame it for my predicament.

Once I got Ventura running I installed XCode 15.  But that gave me "XCode Mismatch" errors when I tried to pair the Mac with Visual Studio on my Windows desktop.  So I binned it and downloaded XCode 14.3.1 from the dev store.  Now I can pair Mac to Windows.

The problem is with iOS Simulator.  It does not work at all.  When I start one (e.g. iPhone 8 or iPhone 13) I get a black screen.  Then (if I'm lucky) I get an Apple logo and a progress bar for about 10 minutes (I'm told this is normal).  But then the simulator screen just goes back to all black and never changes.  Clicking the Home button does nothing.  Behind the scenes it looks like multiple iOS apps are crashing.  For example:

```
Hardware Model:      Macmini7,1
Process:             promotedcontentd [846]
Path:                /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/promotedcontentd
Identifier:          promotedcontentd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [703]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.FA957CBF-6EE1-4033-AB22-58EA1B758777 [837]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [695]

Date/Time:           2023-09-27 23:51:43.4045 +1000
Launch Time:         2023-09-27 23:50:03.6542 +1000
OS Version:          macOS 13.6 (22G120)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process: exc handler [846]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   APFoundation                           0x10035842a 0x10033a000 + 123946
1   APFoundation                           0x10034a486 APSimulateCrash + 601
2   APConfigurationSystem                  0x100325f5e 0x100321000 + 20318
3   APConfigurationSystem                  0x1003273b7 0x100321000 + 25527
4   APConfigurationSystem                  0x1003263e0 0x100321000 + 21472
5   CoreFoundation                         0x103b819ed ___forwarding___ + 810
6   CoreFoundation                         0x103b83e08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
7   promotedcontentd                       0x100138d9e 0x100077000 + 794014
8   promotedcontentd                       0x10014e43c 0x100077000 + 881724
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80172d0d9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80172e493 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
11  promotedcontentd                       0x10014e428 0x100077000 + 881704
12  promotedcontentd                       0x10014e912 0x100077000 + 882962
13  promotedcontentd                       0x10014e615 0x100077000 + 882197
14  promotedcontentd                       0x10013912d 0x100077000 + 794925
15  promotedcontentd                       0x1001493e7 0x100077000 + 861159
16  promotedcontentd                       0x10007b801 0x100077000 + 18433
17  promotedcontentd                       0x10007b645 0x100077000 + 17989
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80172d0d9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80172e493 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
20  promotedcontentd                       0x10007b629 0x100077000 + 17961
21  promotedcontentd                       0x1000792ae 0x100077000 + 8878
22  dyld_sim                               0x1003de384 start_sim + 10
23  dyld                                   0x108e8c41f start + 1903
…
```

At this point the whole computer becomes so slow as to be unusable.  I think that this is because the crash logging is trying behind the scenes to produce enormous memory dumps.  So I’m mainly focused on trying to prevent the crashes and get the iPhone simulator to finish booting successfully.

Could this be related to the way that I started with XCode 15 and then backtracked?  Or do these crashes indicate problems with OCLP, or that my Mac Mini is just not up to the job?

**UPDATE:**

Today I created a device for iPhone XR with iOS 17.0.  When I launched it, it showed the Apple startup progress bar for about 30 minutes.  When that finally finished, I got the inevitable black screen.  I don't think there were any crashes this time, but I just can't get any sign of life from the simulated phone.  I started Xcode and opened a Hello World project and ran it on the simulated device.  Xcode shows "Launching MyApp..." and "Attaching to MyApp on iPhone..." but it just sits forever.  Meanwhile, nothing but a black screen on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had (limited) success with iOS 14.1.  At least I can start a simulator.  It seems that iOS 16 and 17 were way too much for my hardware to handle.